# how many time the characters of string are to be found in another string

Tags: java, string, constructor

my professor gave me an exercise to find how many time the characters of string called "filter" are to be found in a second string called "query".
before I begin I am java noob and English isnt my native language.

example:

```
String filter="kjasd";
String query="kjg4t";

Output:2
```

getting how many times a char has been found in another string isnt my problem but the problem that the professor gave us some rules to stick with:

- class filter. The class must be the following public
  Provide interfaces:

  - public Filter (String letters) (→ Constructor of class) 
    The string representing the filter should be stored in the letters string
  - public boolean contains (char character) 
    Returns true if the passed character is contained in the query string, otherwise false
    -public String toString ()
    Returns an appropriate string representation of the class (just to be clear I have no clue about what does he means with this one!)
  - To actually determine the occurrences of the filter in the query, another class QueryResolver is to be created.
  - The class should be able to be used as follows:

    `QueryResolver resolver = new QueryResolver();
    int count = resolver.where(query).matches(filter).count();`
  - the filter and the query are given by the user.
  - (i couldnt understand this one! )The methods "where" and "matches" configure the "QueryResolver" to include a subsequent call of "count" the calculation based on the previously passed variables
    "query" and "filter" performs.
  - The count method should use the filter's previously-created method.
- The modifier static is not allowed to use!
  I dunno if he means that we cant use `static {}` or we cant use `public (static) boolean contains (char character){}`
- we are not allowed to use void

**so the problems that encountered me**
- I can not pass a char to the method contains as long as it is not static.
error "Non-static variable can not be referenced from a static context"

- i did not understand what i should do with the method toStirng!

**what I've done so far:**

- **Approach Nr 1:** 
  so I just wrote everything in the main method to check whether the principle of my code works or not and then I wanted to create that whole with constructor and other methods but unfortunately I did not succeed.
- **Approach Nr 2:**
  then I tried to write the code in small mthoden as in the exercise but I did not succeed !.

in both aprroaches i violated the exercise rules but i cant seem to be able to do it alone thats why i posted the question here.

**FIRST APPROACH:**

```
public class filter{
    public filter(String letters) {
        //constructor of the class
        String filter;
        int count;
    }
    public boolean contains (char character){
        /*Subprogram without static!
         *the problem that I can't pass any char to this method if it wasn't static
         *and I will get the following error"Non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context"
         *I understand why I'm getting the error but I don't know how to get around it X(   */

       return true ;    
    }

    public String toString (){
        /*he told us to include it in the program but honestly, I don't know what shall I write in it -_-
         *I make it to null because you have to return something and I don't know what to do yet 
         *so, for now, I let it null. */
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in =new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("please enter the query string! ");

        String query= in.next();
        System.out.println("please enter the filter stirng!");

        String filter= in.next();
        System.out.println("the query string is : [" + query+ "]");
        System.out.println("the filter string is : [" + filter+ "]");

        int count=0;

        // I initialized it temporarily because I wanted to print it!
        //later I need to use it with the boolean contains as a public method
        boolean contains=false;

        //to convert each the query and the filter strings to chars
        char [] tempArray=query.toCharArray();
        char [] tempArray1=filter.toCharArray();

        //to iterate for each char in the query string! 
        for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {

            char cc = tempArray[i];
            //to iterate for each char in the filter string!
            for (int j = 0; j < tempArray1.length; j++) {
                // if the value in the filter string matches the value in the temp array then increment the counter by one!
                if(tempArray1[j] == cc){
                    count++;
                    contains=true;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("the characters of the String ["+filter+"] has been found in the forworded string ["+query+"] exactly "+count+" times!" );
        System.out.println("the boolean value : "+ contains);
        in.close();

    }

}
```

**SECOND APPROACH**
 - But here too I violated the rules of the task quite brutally :(
 - First, I used void and did not use the tostring method.
 - Second, I did not use a constructor.
 - I did not add comments because that's just the same principal as my first attempt.

```
public class filter2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the filter string:");
        String filterStr=in.next();
        System.out.println("enter the query string:");
        String querystr =in.next();

        Filter(filterStr, querystr);
        in.close();
    }
    public static void Filter(String filterstr , String querystr){

        char [] tempArray1 = filterstr.toCharArray();
        contains(tempArray1, querystr);
    }   

    public static void contains(char[]tempArray1, String querystr){
        boolean isThere= false ;
        int counter=0;

        char [] tempArray = querystr.toCharArray(); 

        for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {

            char cc = tempArray[i];

            for (int j = 0; j < tempArray1.length; j++) {
                if(tempArray1[j] == cc){
                    counter++;
                    isThere=true;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("the letters of the filter string has been found in the query string exactly "+counter+" times!\nthus the boolean value is "+isThere);

    }
        /*
     * sadly enough i still have no clue what is meant with this one nor whatshall i do
     * public String toString (){
     *  return null;
     * }
     * 
     */
}
```

Few hints and advice would be very useful to me but please demonstrate your suggestions in code because sometimes it can be difficult for me to understand what you mean by the given advice. ;)

Thank you in advance.

(sorry for the gramatical and the type mistakes; english is not my native language)

Comment: Well done, finally someone who sticks to the rules. You posted the problem in detail, you showed us your attempts and asked specific questions. I wish all the beginners would act that way.

Comment: To be honest, I think there is still some knowledge that you need about how java classes work. What you _should_ do is talk to someone who is better at it and let him give you hints. We can't do that here, because that is not how stackoverflow works. Nonetheless, I am impressed by how much effort you made asking this question, therefore I DO offer to post the entire solution, if you want me to.

Comment: @Finomnis my friend the main problem is that I study in Germany it's my first semester and the main question is in German so I tried to do my best to translate it to English. I have a little background about how classes work but I can't seem to get this exercise done. if I don't solve this I'm afraid that I have to do the subject in the next semester and waste 6 months of hard work :(.
of course, please, if you can post the solution I would be so grateful. you are a life-saver.

Comment: @Finomnis I already spoke with my professor to give me some hint about the solution but the answer that I get is "you better learn more" even though this certain topic hasn't been discussed in his previous lectures. I want to learn and I put real effort into learning but I don't want to be misunderstood that I need just the solution without learning. but I've been reading and looking youtube videos for the past couple days and I can't seem to get this right. so your help would be really appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Comment: In this case, i'll try to make the solution as explained as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, it is important to learn to solve those problems yourself. The homework is not for punishment, but to teach you how to learn new stuff on your own, which is an important trait of a computer scientist.

Nonetheless, because it seems like you really made some effort to solve it yourself already, here is my solution, followed by some explanation.

## General concepts

The first thing that I feel like you didn't understand is the concept of classes and objects. A class is like a 'blueprint' of an object, and the object is once you instanciated it.
Compared with something like a car, the *class* would be the description how to build a car, and the *object* would be a car.

You describe what a class is with `public class Car { ... }`, and instanciate an object of it with `Car myCar = new Car();`.

A class can have methods(=functions) and member variables(=data).

I just repeat those concepts because the code that you wrote looks like you didn't fully understand that concept yet. Please ask some other student who understood it to help you with that.

## The *Filter* class

```java
public class Filter{

    String letters;
    
    public Filter(String letters) {
        this.letters = letters;
    }
    
    public boolean contains (char character){
        for(int i = 0; i < letters.length(); i++) {
            if(letters.charAt(i) == character)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String toString (){
        return "Filter(" + letters + ")";
    }
}
```

Ok, let's brake that down.

```java
public class Filter{
...
}
```

I guess you already got that part. This is where you describe your class structure.

```java
    String letters;
```

This is a class member variable. It is unique for every object that you create of that class. Again, for details, ask other students that understood it.

```java
    public Filter(String letters) {
        this.letters = letters;
    }
```

This is the constructor. When you create your object, this is the function that gets called.
In this case, all it does is to take an argument `letters` and stores it in the class-variable `letters`. Because they have the same name, you need to explicitely tell java that the left one is the class variable. You do this by adding `this.`.

```java
    public boolean contains (char character){
        for(int i = 0; i < letters.length(); i++) {
            if(letters.charAt(i) == character)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This takes a character and looks whether it is contained in `this.letters` or not.
Because there is no name collision here, you can ommit the `this.`.

If I understood right, the missing `static` here was one of your problems. If you have `static`, the function is class-bound and not object-bound, meaning you can call it without having an object. Again, it is important that you understand the difference, and if you don't, ask someone. (To be precise, ask the difference between class, object, static and non-static) It would take too long to explain that in detail here.

But in a nutshell, if the function is **not** static, it needs to be called on an object to work. Look further down in the other class for details how that looks like.

```
    public String toString (){
        return "Filter(" + letters + ")";
    }
```

This function is also non-static. It is used whenever the object needs to be converted to a String, like in a `System.out.println()` call. Again, it is important here that you understand the difference between class and object.

## The *QueryResolver* class

```java
public class QueryResolver {

    Filter filter;
    String query;
    
    public QueryResolver where(String queryStr) {
        this.query = queryStr;
        return this;        
    }

    public QueryResolver matches(String filterStr) {
        this.filter = new Filter(filterStr);
        return this;        
    }
        
    public int count() {
        int result = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < query.length(); i++) {
            if(filter.contains(query.charAt(i))){
                result++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Again, let's break that down.

```java
public class QueryResolver {
...
}
```

Our class body.

Note that we don't have a constructor here. It is advisable to have one, but in this case it would be an empty function with no arguments that does nothing, so we can just leave it and the compiler will auto-generate it.

```java
    public QueryResolver where(String queryStr) {
        this.query = queryStr;
        return this;        
    }
```

This is an interesting function. It returns a `this` pointer. Therefore you can use the result of the function to do another call, allowing you to 'chain' multiple function calls together, like `resolver.where(query).matches(filter).count()`.

To understand how that works requires you to understand both the class-object difference and what exactly the `this` pointer does.
The short version is that the `this` pointer is the pointer to the object that our function currently lives in.

```java
    public QueryResolver matches(String filterStr) {
        this.filter = new Filter(filterStr);
        return this;        
    }
```

This is almost the same as the `where` function.

The interesting part is the `new Filter(...)`. This creates the previously discussed `Filter`-object from the class description and puts it in the `QueryResolver` object's `this.filter` variable.

```java
    public int count() {
        int result = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < query.length(); i++) {
            if(filter.contains(query.charAt(i))){
                result++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Iterates through the object's `query` variable and checks for every letter if it is contained in `filter`. It keeps count of how many times this happens and returns the count.

This function requires that `filter` and `query` are set. Therefore it is important that before someone calls `count()`, they previously call `where(..)` and `matches(..)`.
In our case, all of that happens in one line, `resolver.where(query).matches(filter).count()`.

## The *main* function

I wrote two different `main` functions. You want to test your code as much as possible during development, therefore the first one I wrote was a fixed one, where you don't have to enter something manually, just click run and it works:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String filter="kjasd";
        String query="kjg4t";
        
        
        QueryResolver resolver = new QueryResolver();
        int count = resolver.where(query).matches(filter).count();
        
        System.out.println(count);
    }
```

Once you understand the class-object difference, this should be straight forward.
But to repeat:

```java
    QueryResolver resolver = new QueryResolver();
```

This creates your QueryResolver object and stores it in the variable `resolver`.

```java
    int count = resolver.where(query).matches(filter).count();
```

Then, this line uses the `resolver` object to first call `where`, `matches`, and finally `count`. Again, this chaining only works because we return `this` in the `where` and `matches` functions.

Now finally the interactive version that you created:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("please enter the query string! ");

        String query= in.next();
        System.out.println("please enter the filter stirng!");

        String filter= in.next();
        System.out.println("the query string is : [" + query+ "]");
        System.out.println("the filter string is : [" + filter+ "]");

        QueryResolver resolver = new QueryResolver();
        int count = resolver.where(query).matches(filter).count();
        
        System.out.println("the characters of the String ["+filter+"] has been found in the forworded string ["+query+"] exactly "+count+" times!" );
        in.close();
    }
```

Comment: man, I don't know how to thank you enough for this. but as you told I will go now and make a detailed search for the difference between class, object, static and non-static. I need to understand them better after all. I will take everything you told into my consideration. Actually, I didn't know about the "this" part and the chained call. thanks for taking the time trying to explain to me all the things that I didn't get it right. you helped me so much and therefore I'm really really thankful.

Comment: Today I have been trying to do some extra stuff just to exercise and to train my brain ;). could you pls tell me if you would be still willing to help if a question or a problem pops up or not ;). I don't want to be nagging around or stress you because you already have done so much. I just asked because you did explain the whole thing very good to me and you have a background about what we did and I would rather console you in case of problem or question than posting a new question.

Comment: the extra features are: - ``public boolean once()``: Returns true if exactly one single character from "query" is also part of the "filter" - ``public boolean one()`` : Returns true if exactly one character of the filter is found minimum once in the query. - ``public boolean any ()``: Returns true if at least one of the characters from query is also part of the filter - ``public boolean none()``: Returns true if none of the characters from query is also part of the filter - ``public boolean every()``: Returns true if every character from query is also part of the filter

Comment: those shall be in QueryResolver which is okay. but what I'm concern about is that the code works in the following order filter→query (check for the chars of filter in query) but what is making me concern that each of ``any`` ``once`` ``none`` ``every`` work in the counter order query→filter. what I thought for the ``every`` is when the length of the first string and the length of the second string are the same && the result is equal to the length of either one of the strings then ``true``. i know that using ``equals`` won't help as well. lemme know what you think pls (just tips) ;)

Comment: If by filter->query order you mean the order of `where` and `matches`, those two are independent from each other and can be called in any order, as you should see in the implementation of the functions. The only important thing is that both get called, as you can see in `count()`, because there both `filter` and `query` get used, meaning, they both need to be present.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the purpose of `every`. I don't think the strings need to be equal, query `'test'` should return true for the filter `'setting'`, because all the characters of `'test'` are in `'setting'`. Length doesn't matter.
Try to copy the `count()` function, and try to adjust it to the functionality of the other tasks :) If you want, we can continue on discord/telegram for more questions, I don't wanna blow up this thread too much

Comment: great idea :) I would like to complete the work on telegram [link](https://t.me/studentaccount4) 
what I meant is when we have the ``String filter= "abc";`` and ``String query="abc";`` then the counter will show the result of 3.
I thought if they are at the same length and the counter is equal to the length of either of those strings then that would mean that the counter is 3 and the length is 3 so each char of the string is equal to the other. but I couldn't make this happen. working on your suggestion now
so when you have time I provided a link just send me. again thanks for being helpful